# Remove certain words up until a different set of words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to delete the numbers after a certain word, until a symbol.

So say I have the following string: `jessicaamount=9487&doe`. I want the final string to look like this: `jessica&doe`. (There may not always be anything after the number.)

I'm thinking regex is the solution, but not too sure how I would go about it.

Comment: `str.replace(/amount=\d+/, '')`?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: @Nick That worked! Can you post it as an answer so that I can accept? Thanks

Comment: @Jessica it's fine. I'm happy you have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

An option without regex would be to use `indexOf()` and `.slice()`.

```js
function removeNumber (string) {
  
  let part1 = string.slice(0, string.indexOf("amount="));
  let part2 = string.slice(string.indexOf("&"));
  
  return part1 + part2;
}

console.log(removeNumber("jessicaamount=9487&doe")) // jessica&doe
```

It will remove what is between strings in variables `part1` and `part2`.
It includes the first character of `part2`.